# airflow cannot find file under dags directory

Tags: python, airflow

I have a PostgresOperator that gives the file path to a sql file.

```
   stage_evergreen = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="RefreshStageEvergreen",
        postgres_conn_id="evergreen",
        autocommit=True,
        sql="sql/evergreen_stage.sql")
```

This is a relative path under the dags directory, accordingly to the official tutorial this should work.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html

But it does not work.....

Error is:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: sql/evergreen_stage.sql

I also tried adding `template_searchpath` to my dag decorator :

```
@dag(
dag_id = "Evergreen",
schedule_interval = '0 10 * * *',
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 9, tz="UTC"),
catchup=False,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
template_searchpath = ['/opt/airflow/dags/sql/']
)
```

but still does not work...

Only placing the sql file directly under the dags folder worked for me.

Comment: might be permission problem to sql folder. try to add full permissions and check again

Answer (score 0):

Just try `sql="./sql/evergreen_stage.sql"` if your *dag* file and *sql* folder exist at same parent path.